# Change existing c# code to return some but not all items in a sharepoint list

Tags: web-part

I have implemented a news ticker which (1) extracts all the items in a SharePoint 2013 list and returns them in ul and li tags, and (2) passes the market content to a scroller script which presents them as a ticker tape scroll right to left.

The code for step (1) is from here: http://www.sharepointnadeem.com/2011/09/news-ticker-webpart.html (Thank you Nadeem) I amended it to use a different scroller script - I found that liscroll worked and the one used here didn't.

All list items are returned.

How should I change the step (1) code in order to return a particular view (which is filtered by Show/Hide and sorted by SortOrder?)

Answer (score 2):

Change the following line in the code:

```
SPListItemCollection items = list.Items;
```

To following:

```
SPView view = list.Views["Your View Name"]; //custom view name
SPListItemCollection items = list.GetItems(view);
```

`list.Items` returns all the items from the List while `list.GetItems(SPView)` returns items from only the particular view passed.